# JPA and Hibernate in the same spring project

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Working on an huge complicated application that has hibernate LocalSessionFactoryBean, HibernateTransactionManager and HibernateTemplate being used presently. Is it possible that I can use JPA for my new feature development so that I can use SPRING DATA JPA to work on my persistence layer? My current configuration is below.

```
    <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" destroy-method="destroy"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:/hbm/*.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>classpath*:/hid-hbm/*.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="myDataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

   <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
   </bean>
```

However, I would like to add LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, JpaTransactionManager for the new stuff. Can both of these reside in the same project?

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You may be a bit confused; JPA is the specification and Hibernate is one implementation of it (arguably the most popular ATM).

Comment: @TassosBassoukos although you're comment is right, he's using the actual Hibernate Framework, not the JPA implementation of that.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, your comment is confusing. There are not two implementations of Hibernate. Hibernate has a native API and also implements the JPA specification, but they are the same implementation; there is only one version of Hibernate binaries.

Comment: @DavidS, The exact reason why I ask this question is because of the fact that behind native hibernate API and JPA specification lies hibernate binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... Yes, you can mix and match both as long you keep both implementations completely isolated.

That will also give you ability to migrate the "legacy" hibernate DAOs to Spring Data in future dates.

Glancing your code, it all looks good to me but I'm not sure how the Transaction Management will behave in cases when your service needs DAOs/Repos from both implementations.

Comment: the scenario that I am thinking is that when ( it going to happen eventually in my new feature) new feature talks to the old feature, and something goes wrong on the old feature transaction, stuff will be rolled back. But the new stuff will go through because nothing goes wrong on its end.

Comment: Yeah @NikhilThakur, I believe with the right transaction demarcation, you should be fine as you're using the same tx manager for both DAO layers. Remember tx managers are a level above the DB and it should transparent for you as a developer if you are using one two or ten different DBs.